# What is the benefit to using typing library classes vs. types in Python type hints?

Tags: python, type-hinting, static-typing

I'm starting to learn type hints in Python to ease the future porting of code from Python to C. I am wondering what the difference is, if any, between using types directly in type hints vs. using the classes defined in the `typing` module.

For example, the difference between

```
def somefn(a: list[int]) -> tuple[str, int]:
    ...
```

and

```
from typing import List, Tuple

def somefn(a: List[int]) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    ...
```

It seems like some classes like `Union`, `Any`, `Callable`, and `Iterable` would be useful, but the utility of classes for data types that already exist as keywords in python is unclear to me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's useful for writing annotations that can be legally evaluated; `list[int]` will explode if you try to actually run it, while `typing.List[int]` returns a new generic type that knows the type of both container and contents. This is particularly important in the case of [type aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases), where a specialized version of a generic is defined at the top level, then reused as annotation further on:

```
Vector = List[float]
def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
     ...
```

is legal, while:

```
Vector = list[float]
def scale(scalar: float, vector: Vector) -> Vector:
     ...
```

blows up in your face. You'll note that non-container/generic types typically don't have a `typing` type (exceptions like `Text` are for porting concerns), because type aliases would only use them as "leaf" type, not root or branch types.

**Update:** As of 3.9, [the standard collections can serve as type hints](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections), so the `typing` types aren't strictly necessary; you can continue to use them if you like (necessary for code that must run on pre-3.9 Python), but it's not necessary if you can rely on 3.9+.